# How to find all hyperlinks within Publishing pages?

Tags: publishing-page, hyperlink, fast-search

In our SharePoint 2010 Farm there is one sitecollection where users can create and edit pages (Publishing feature). We need a list of all the hyperlinks the users have inserted into the pages.

For this I would like to use the search. Does FAST Search for SharePoint 2010 extract hyperlinks from content (pages and maybe as a bonus from Office documents) and map it to crawled / managed properties?

If not do I have to extend the FAST Search Pipeline with custom extractor? Or is there any other alternative to this?

Comment: Please specify the SharePoint version

Comment: SharePoint 2010, FAST Search for SharePoint 2010